# Unexpected shape returned from function mapped to tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I tried to pad a dataset containing tensors of varying length in the first dimension. The lengths are any number up to 13 and I would like to pad zeros to the front at the first dimension. It seems the function is working properly when I apply it on a tensor but the dataset didn't return a shape of (13,128) as I expected. I got a shape of (None, None).

The code goes like this:

```
print(train_dataset_filtered.element_spec, '\n')

def pad_seq(eng, ger):
    n = 13 - tf.shape(eng)[0]
    paddings = tf.concat(([[n,0]], [[0,0]]), axis=0)
    return tf.pad(eng, paddings), ger

print(pad_seq(tf.ones((4,128)), tf.ones((14,))), '\n')

print(train_dataset_filtered.map(pad_seq).element_spec)
```

The output is as follows:

```
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(14,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)) 

(<tf.Tensor: id=402, shape=(13, 128), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: id=388, shape=(14,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
      dtype=float32)>) 

(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(14,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of `n = 13 - tf.shape(eng)[0]` is causing this behavior here when you use `concat()`.

In your example it is `tf.Tensor(9, shape=(), dtype=int32)`. So the best way is to use `stack()`. Change your code with:

```
def pad_seq(eng, ger):
    n = 13 - tf.shape(eng)[0]
    paddings = tf.stack(([[n,0], [0,0]]))
    return (tf.pad(eng, paddings), ger)
```

Also I noticed you did not accept any answers in SO. Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: First of all, thank you so much! I implemented your suggestion and got an output shape of (None, 128). I tried to inspect the output and it seems all outputs are in the shape of (13, 128) but the element_spec showed (None, 128). Even if I increased the padding to some arbitrary large number e.g. 10000, the output shape is still (None, 128). Can you think of a reason why this is the case? Thanks again!

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code, but it might be because you mapped a function that makes the output 128 dimensions. If you want to inspect the shape of the elements then you need to take an example from dataset with `take()` method. If you want to see the effect of i.e padding = 1000, you should inspect the shape of the elements.